# strange with downloading modules python 3.5

Tags: python, module, download, python-idle, miniconda

I have used miniconda and pip to download modules such as matplotlib. The modules works fine when I work in command prompt, but doesn't work when I try to import in my IDLE 3.5 version

Comment: Please be more specific. _How_ does it not work? What did you try to make it work? Are there any error messages? What exactly they are?

Comment: Can't find it import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Anaconda (and miniconda, I assume) stores modules in its own folder. Is your IDLE a part of the conda distribution? If it is not, then if does not know where to find `numpy`. (If IDLE is a part of conda, it starts Anaconda Python.)

Comment: you can have more Pythons installed and IDLE can use different Python which doesn't have matplotlib installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your command prompt is using a different version of Python. I know that may not be the case, but there is a difference between `python`, `python2`, `python3`, and even more changes in a `virtualenv`.

In your command prompt (where the module works), type in `python`, and try to import your module. If it works, check what version of you are using.

For instance, here is what happens when I type in `python3` into my terminal.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

From that, you can see I am using Python `3.4.3`.

Now in IDLE, confirm that the versions match, if they do not, then you can work to solving the problem.

Problem still persisting?

You may have two versions (somehow) in different locations. Open up the command prompt and IDLE and type these 3 commands in each

`import sys`

`sys.version`

`sys.path`

Make sure `sys.path` is the same in both.

I hope I helped!